# Заменить тег <h3> на <div> в Gravity Form

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

В форме [Gravity Form](https://www.gravityforms.com/) (Version 2.4.21) не могу найти хук как заменить тег с классом `<h3 class="gform_title">` на `<div class="gform_title">`. Путём `javascript` не подходит. Менять в плагине не есть хорошо

Шорткод для вывода формы по id:

```
?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id=4 title=true description=false ajax=true]' ); ?>
```

Метод который регенерирует форму:

```
public static function get_form( $form_id, $display_title = true, $display_description = true, $force_display = false, $field_values = null, $ajax = false, $tabindex = 0 ) {

        /**
         * Provides the ability to modify the options used to display the form
         *
         * @param array An array of Form Arguments when adding it to a page/post (Like the ID, Title, AJAX or not, etc)
         */
        $form_args = apply_filters( 'gform_form_args', compact( 'form_id', 'display_title', 'display_description', 'force_display', 'field_values', 'ajax', 'tabindex' ) );

        if ( empty( $form_args['form_id'] ) ) {
            return self::get_form_not_found_html( $form_id );
        }

        extract( $form_args );

        //looking up form id by form name
        if ( ! is_numeric( $form_id ) ) {
            $form_title = $form_id;
            $form_id    = GFFormsModel::get_form_id( $form_title );
            if ( $form_id === 0 ) {
                return self::get_form_not_found_html( $form_title );
            }
        }

        $form = GFAPI::get_form( $form_id );

        if ( ! $form ) {
            return self::get_form_not_found_html( $form_id );
        }

        $action = remove_query_arg( 'gf_token' );

        if ( rgpost( 'gform_send_resume_link' ) == $form_id ) {
            $save_email_confirmation = self::handle_save_email_confirmation( $form, $ajax );
            if ( is_wp_error( $save_email_confirmation ) ) { // Failed email validation
                $resume_token               = rgpost( 'gform_resume_token' );
                $resume_token = sanitize_key( $resume_token );
                $incomplete_submission_info = GFFormsModel::get_draft_submission_values( $resume_token );
                if ( $incomplete_submission_info['form_id'] == $form_id ) {
                    $submission_details_json = $incomplete_submission_info['submission'];
                    $submission_details      = json_decode( $submission_details_json, true );
                    $partial_entry           = $submission_details['partial_entry'];
                    $form                    = self::update_confirmation( $form, $partial_entry, 'form_saved' );
                    $confirmation_message    = rgar( $form['confirmation'], 'message' );
                    $nl2br                   = rgar( $form['confirmation'], 'disableAutoformat' ) ? false : true;
                    $confirmation_message    = GFCommon::replace_variables( $confirmation_message, $form, $partial_entry, false, true, $nl2br );

                    return self::handle_save_confirmation( $form, $resume_token, $confirmation_message, $ajax );
                }
            } else {
                return $save_email_confirmation;
            }
        }

        $is_postback          = false;
        $is_valid             = true;
        $confirmation_message = '';

        //If form was submitted, read variables set during form submission procedure
        $submission_info = isset( self::$submission[ $form_id ] ) ? self::$submission[ $form_id ] : false;

        if ( rgar( $submission_info, 'saved_for_later' ) == true ) {
            $resume_token         = $submission_info['resume_token'];
            $confirmation_message = rgar( $submission_info, 'confirmation_message' );

            return self::handle_save_confirmation( $form, $resume_token, $confirmation_message, $ajax );
        }

        $partial_entry = $submitted_values = $review_page_done = false;
        if ( isset( $_GET['gf_token'] ) ) {
            $incomplete_submission_info = GFFormsModel::get_draft_submission_values( $_GET['gf_token'] );
            if ( rgar( $incomplete_submission_info, 'form_id' ) == $form_id ) {
                $submission_details_json                  = $incomplete_submission_info['submission'];
                $submission_details                       = json_decode( $submission_details_json, true );
                $partial_entry                            = $submission_details['partial_entry'];
                $submitted_values                         = $submission_details['submitted_values'];
                $field_values                             = $submission_details['field_values'];
                GFFormsModel::$unique_ids[ $form_id ]     = $submission_details['gform_unique_id'];
                GFFormsModel::$uploaded_files[ $form_id ] = $submission_details['files'];
                self::set_submission_if_null( $form_id, 'resuming_incomplete_submission', true );
                self::set_submission_if_null( $form_id, 'form_id', $form_id );

                $form             = self::maybe_add_review_page( $form, $partial_entry );
                $review_page_done = true;

                $max_page_number = self::get_max_page_number( $form );
                $page_number     = $submission_details['page_number'];
                if ( $page_number > 1 && $max_page_number > 0 && $page_number > $max_page_number ) {
                    $page_number = $max_page_number;
                }
                self::set_submission_if_null( $form_id, 'page_number', $page_number );
            }
        }

        if ( ! $review_page_done && $form !== false ) {
            $form = self::maybe_add_review_page( $form );
        }

        if ( ! is_array( $partial_entry ) ) {

            /**
             * A filter that allows disabling of the form view counter
             *
             * @param int $form_id The Form ID to filter when disabling the form view counter
             * @param bool Default set to false (view counter enabled), can be set to true to disable the counter
             */
            $view_counter_disabled = gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_disable_view_counter', $form_id ), false );

            if ( $submission_info ) {
                $is_postback          = true;
                $is_valid             = rgar( $submission_info, 'is_valid' ) || rgar( $submission_info, 'is_confirmation' );
                $form                 = $submission_info['form'];
                $lead                 = $submission_info['lead'];
                $confirmation_message = rgget( 'confirmation_message', $submission_info );

                if ( $is_valid && ! RGForms::get( 'is_confirmation', $submission_info ) ) {

                    if ( $submission_info['page_number'] == 0 ) {
                        /**
                         * Fired after form submission
                         *
                         * @param array $lead The Entry object
                         * @param array $form The Form object
                         */
                        gf_do_action( array( 'gform_post_submission', $form['id'] ), $lead, $form );
                    } else {
                        /**
                         * Fired after the page changes on a multi-page form
                         *
                         * @param array $form                                  The Form object
                         * @param int   $submission_info['source_page_number'] The page that was submitted
                         * @param int   $submission_info['page_number']        The page that the user is being sent to
                         */
                        gf_do_action( array( 'gform_post_paging', $form['id'] ), $form, $submission_info['source_page_number'], $submission_info['page_number'] );
                    }
                }
            } elseif ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && ! $view_counter_disabled ) {
                RGFormsModel::insert_form_view( $form_id );
            }
        }

        if ( rgar( $form, 'enableHoneypot' ) ) {
            $form['fields'][] = self::get_honeypot_field( $form );
        }

        //Fired right before the form rendering process. Allow users to manipulate the form object before it gets displayed in the front end
        $form = gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_pre_render', $form_id ), $form, $ajax, $field_values );

        if ( empty( $form ) ) {
            return self::get_form_not_found_html( $form_id );
        }

        $has_pages = self::has_pages( $form );

        //calling tab index filter
        GFCommon::$tab_index = gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_tabindex', $form_id ), $tabindex, $form );

        //Don't display inactive forms
        if ( ! $force_display && ! $is_postback ) {

            $form_info = RGFormsModel::get_form( $form_id );
            if ( empty( $form_info ) || ! $form_info->is_active ) {
                return '';
            }

            // If form requires login, check if user is logged in
            if ( rgar( $form, 'requireLogin' ) ) {
                if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    return empty( $form['requireLoginMessage'] ) ? '<p>' . esc_html__( 'Sorry. You must be logged in to view this form.', 'gravityforms' ) . '</p>' : '<p>' . GFCommon::gform_do_shortcode( $form['requireLoginMessage'] ) . '</p>';
                }
            }
        }

        // show the form regardless of the following validations when force display is set to true
        if ( ! $force_display || $is_postback ) {

            $form_schedule_validation = self::validate_form_schedule( $form );

            // if form schedule validation fails AND this is not a postback, display the validation error
            // if form schedule validation fails AND this is a postback, make sure is not a valid submission (enables display of confirmation message)
            if ( $form_schedule_validation && ! $is_postback ) {
                return $form_schedule_validation;
            } elseif ( $form_schedule_validation && $is_postback && ! $is_valid ) {
                return self::get_ajax_postback_html( $form_schedule_validation );
            }

            $entry_limit_validation = self::validate_entry_limit( $form );

            // refer to form schedule condition notes above
            if ( $entry_limit_validation && ! $is_postback ) {
                return $entry_limit_validation;
            } elseif ( $entry_limit_validation && $is_postback && ! $is_valid ) {
                return self::get_ajax_postback_html( $entry_limit_validation );
            }

        }

        $form_string = '';

        //When called via a template, this will enqueue the proper scripts
        //When called via a shortcode, this will be ignored (too late to enqueue), but the scripts will be enqueued via the enqueue_scripts event
        self::enqueue_form_scripts( $form, $ajax );

        $is_form_editor  = GFCommon::is_form_editor();
        $is_entry_detail = GFCommon::is_entry_detail();
        $is_admin        = $is_form_editor || $is_entry_detail;

        if ( empty( $confirmation_message ) ) {
            $wrapper_css_class = GFCommon::get_browser_class() . ' gform_wrapper';

            if ( ! $is_valid ) {
                $wrapper_css_class .= ' gform_validation_error';
            }

            $form_css_class = esc_attr( rgar( $form, 'cssClass' ) );

            //Hiding entire form if conditional logic is on to prevent 'hidden' fields from blinking. Form will be set to visible in the conditional_logic.php after the rules have been applied.
            $style                    = self::has_conditional_logic( $form ) ? "style='display:none'" : '';

            // Split form CSS class by spaces and apply wrapper to each.
            $custom_wrapper_css_class = '';
            if ( ! empty( $form_css_class ) ) {

                // Separate the CSS classes.
                $form_css_classes = explode( ' ', $form_css_class );

                // Append _wrapper to each class.
                foreach ( $form_css_classes as &$wrapper_class ) {
                    $wrapper_class .= '_wrapper';
                }

                // Merge back into a string.
                $custom_wrapper_css_class = ' ' . implode( ' ', $form_css_classes );

            }

            $form_string .= "
                <div class='{$wrapper_css_class}{$custom_wrapper_css_class}' id='gform_wrapper_$form_id' " . $style . '>';

            $anchor      = self::get_anchor( $form, $ajax );
            $form_string .= $anchor['tag'];
            $action      .= $anchor['id'];

            $target = $ajax ? "target='gform_ajax_frame_{$form_id}'" : '';

            $form_css_class = ! empty( $form['cssClass'] ) ? "class='{$form_css_class}'" : '';

            $action = esc_url( $action );
            $form_string .= gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_form_tag', $form_id ), "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' {$target} id='gform_{$form_id}' {$form_css_class} action='{$action}'>", $form );

            if ( $display_title || $display_description ) {
                $form_string .= "
                        <div class='gform_heading'>";
                if ( $display_title ) {
                    $form_string .= "
                            <h3 class='gform_title'>" . esc_html( $form['title'] ) . '</h3>';
                }
                if ( $display_description ) {
                    $form_string .= "
                            <span class='gform_description'>" . rgar( $form, 'description' ) . '</span>';
                }
                $form_string .= '
                        </div>';
            }

            // If Save and Continue token was provided but expired/invalid, display error message.
            if ( isset( $_GET['gf_token'] ) && ! is_array( $incomplete_submission_info ) ) {

                /**
                 * Modify the error message displayed when an expired/invalid Save and Continue link is used.
                 *
                 * @since 2.4
                 *
                 * @param string $message Save & Continue expired/invalid link error message.
                 * @param array  $form    The current Form object.
                 */
                $savecontinue_expired_message = gf_apply_filters( array(
                    'gform_savecontinue_expired_message',
                    $form['id'],
                ), esc_html__( 'Save and Continue link used is expired or invalid.', 'gravityforms' ), $form );

                // If message is not empty, add to form string.
                if ( ! empty( $savecontinue_expired_message ) ) {
                    $form_string .= sprintf(
                        '<div class="validation_error">%s</div>',
                        $savecontinue_expired_message
                    );
                }

            }

            /* If the form was submitted, has multiple pages and is invalid, set the current page to the first page with an invalid field. */
            if ( $has_pages && $is_postback && ! $is_valid ) {
                self::set_current_page( $form_id, GFFormDisplay::get_first_page_with_error( $form ) );
            }

            $current_page = self::get_current_page( $form_id );

            if ( $has_pages && ! $is_admin ) {

                if ( $form['pagination']['type'] == 'percentage' ) {
                    $form_string .= self::get_progress_bar( $form, $current_page, $confirmation_message );
                } else if ( $form['pagination']['type'] == 'steps' ) {
                    $form_string .= self::get_progress_steps( $form, $current_page );
                }
            }

            if ( $is_postback && ! $is_valid ) {
                if ( gf_upgrade()->get_submissions_block() ){
                    $validation_message = "<div class='gf_submission_limit_message'><p>" . esc_html__( 'Your form was not submitted. Please try again in a few minutes.', 'gravityforms' ) . '</p></div>';
                } else {
                    $validation_message = "<div class='validation_error'>" . esc_html__( 'There was a problem with your submission.', 'gravityforms' ) . ' ' . esc_html__( 'Errors have been highlighted below.', 'gravityforms' ) . '</div>';
                }
                $form_string .= gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_validation_message', $form_id ), $validation_message, $form );
            }

            $form_string .= "
                        <div class='gform_body'>";

            //add first page if this form has any page fields
            if ( $has_pages ) {
                $style = self::is_page_active( $form_id, 1 ) ? '' : "style='display:none;'";
                $class = ! empty( $form['firstPageCssClass'] ) ? " {$form['firstPageCssClass']}" : '';
                $class = esc_attr( $class );
                $form_string .= "<div id='gform_page_{$form_id}_1' class='gform_page{$class}' {$style}>
                                    <div class='gform_page_fields'>";
            }

            $description_class = rgar( $form, 'descriptionPlacement' ) == 'above' ? 'description_above' : 'description_below';
            $sublabel_class = rgar( $form, 'subLabelPlacement' ) == 'above' ? 'form_sublabel_above' : 'form_sublabel_below';


            $form_string .= "<ul id='gform_fields_{$form_id}' class='" . GFCommon::get_ul_classes( $form ) . "'>";

            if ( is_array( $form['fields'] ) ) {
                foreach ( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
                    /* @var GF_Field $field */
                    $field->conditionalLogicFields = self::get_conditional_logic_fields( $form, $field->id );

                    if ( is_array( $submitted_values ) ) {
                        $field_value = rgar( $submitted_values, $field->id );

                        if ( $field->type === 'consent'
                             && ( $field_value[ $field->id . '.3' ] != GFFormsModel::get_latest_form_revisions_id( $form['id'] )
                                  || $field_value[ $field->id . '.2' ] != $field->checkboxLabel ) ) {
                            $field_value = GFFormsModel::get_field_value( $field, $field_values );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $field_value = GFFormsModel::get_field_value( $field, $field_values );
                    }

                    $form_string .= self::get_field( $field, $field_value, false, $form, $field_values );
                }
            }
            $form_string .= '
                            </ul>';

            if ( $has_pages ) {
                $previous_button_alt = rgempty( 'imageAlt', $form['lastPageButton'] ) ? __( 'Previous Page', 'gravityforms' ) : $form['lastPageButton']['imageAlt'];
                $previous_button = self::get_form_button( $form['id'], "gform_previous_button_{$form['id']}", $form['lastPageButton'], __( 'Previous', 'gravityforms' ), 'gform_previous_button', $previous_button_alt, self::get_current_page( $form_id ) - 1 );

                /**
                 * Filter through the form previous button when paged
                 *
                 * @param int $form_id The Form ID to filter through
                 * @param string $previous_button The HTML rendered button (rendered with the form ID and the function get_form_button)
                 * @param array $form The Form object to filter through
                 */
                $previous_button = gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_previous_button', $form_id ), $previous_button, $form );
                $form_string .= '</div>' . self::gform_footer( $form, 'gform_page_footer ' . $form['labelPlacement'], $ajax, $field_values, $previous_button, $display_title, $display_description, $is_postback ) . '
                        </div>'; //closes gform_page
            }

            $form_string .= '</div>'; //closes gform_body

            //suppress form footer for multi-page forms (footer will be included on the last page
            if ( ! $has_pages ) {
                $form_string .= self::gform_footer( $form, 'gform_footer ' . $form['labelPlacement'], $ajax, $field_values, '', $display_title, $display_description, $tabindex );
            }

            $form_string .= '
                        </form>
                        </div>';

            if ( $ajax && $is_postback ) {
                global $wp_scripts;

                $form_string = self::get_ajax_postback_html( $form_string );

            }

            if ( $ajax && ! $is_postback ) {
                $spinner_url     = gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_ajax_spinner_url', $form_id ), GFCommon::get_base_url() . '/images/spinner.gif', $form );
                $scroll_position = array( 'default' => '', 'confirmation' => '' );

                if ( $anchor['scroll'] !== false ) {
                    $scroll_position['default']      = is_numeric( $anchor['scroll'] ) ? 'jQuery(document).scrollTop(' . intval( $anchor['scroll'] ) . ');' : "jQuery(document).scrollTop(jQuery('#gform_wrapper_{$form_id}').offset().top - mt);";
                    $scroll_position['confirmation'] = is_numeric( $anchor['scroll'] ) ? 'jQuery(document).scrollTop(' . intval( $anchor['scroll'] ) . ');' : "jQuery(document).scrollTop(jQuery('{$anchor['id']}').offset().top - mt);";
                }

                // Accessibility enhancements to properly handle the iframe title and content.
                $iframe_content = esc_html__( 'This iframe contains the logic required to handle Ajax powered Gravity Forms.', 'gravityforms' );
                $iframe_title   = " title='{$iframe_content}'";
                if ( defined( 'GF_DEBUG' ) && GF_DEBUG ) {
                    // In debug mode, display the iframe with the text content.
                    $iframe_style = 'display:block;width:600px;height:300px;border:1px solid #eee;';
                } else {
                    // Hide the iframe and the content is not needed when not in debug mode.
                    $iframe_style   = 'display:none;width:0px;height:0px;';
                    $iframe_content = '';
                }

                $form_string .= "
                <iframe style='{$iframe_style}' src='about:blank' name='gform_ajax_frame_{$form_id}' id='gform_ajax_frame_{$form_id}'" . $iframe_title . ">" . $iframe_content . "</iframe>
                <script type='text/javascript'>" . apply_filters( 'gform_cdata_open', '' ) . '' .
                    'jQuery(document).ready(function($){' .
                        "gformInitSpinner( {$form_id}, '{$spinner_url}' );" .
                        "jQuery('#gform_ajax_frame_{$form_id}').on('load',function(){" .
                            "var contents = jQuery(this).contents().find('*').html();" .
                            "var is_postback = contents.indexOf('GF_AJAX_POSTBACK') >= 0;" .
                            'if(!is_postback){return;}' .
                            "var form_content = jQuery(this).contents().find('#gform_wrapper_{$form_id}');" .
                            "var is_confirmation = jQuery(this).contents().find('#gform_confirmation_wrapper_{$form_id}').length > 0;" .
                            "var is_redirect = contents.indexOf('gformRedirect(){') >= 0;" .
                            'var is_form = form_content.length > 0 && ! is_redirect && ! is_confirmation;' .
                            "var mt = parseInt(jQuery('html').css('margin-top'), 10) + parseInt(jQuery('body').css('margin-top'), 10) + 100;" .
                            'if(is_form){' .
                                "jQuery('#gform_wrapper_{$form_id}').html(form_content.html());" .
                                "if(form_content.hasClass('gform_validation_error')){jQuery('#gform_wrapper_{$form_id}').addClass('gform_validation_error');} else {jQuery('#gform_wrapper_{$form_id}').removeClass('gform_validation_error');}" .
                                "setTimeout( function() { /* delay the scroll by 50 milliseconds to fix a bug in chrome */ {$scroll_position['default']} }, 50 );" .
                                "if(window['gformInitDatepicker']) {gformInitDatepicker();}" .
                                "if(window['gformInitPriceFields']) {gformInitPriceFields();}" .
                                "var current_page = jQuery('#gform_source_page_number_{$form_id}').val();" .
                                "gformInitSpinner( {$form_id}, '{$spinner_url}' );" .
                                "jQuery(document).trigger('gform_page_loaded', [{$form_id}, current_page]);" .
                                "window['gf_submitting_{$form_id}'] = false;" .
                            '}' .
                            'else if(!is_redirect){' .
                                "var confirmation_content = jQuery(this).contents().find('.GF_AJAX_POSTBACK').html();" .
                                'if(!confirmation_content){' .
                                    'confirmation_content = contents;' .
                                '}' .
                                'setTimeout(function(){' .
                                    "jQuery('#gform_wrapper_{$form_id}').replaceWith(confirmation_content);" .
                                    "{$scroll_position['confirmation']}" .
                                    "jQuery(document).trigger('gform_confirmation_loaded', [{$form_id}]);" .
                                    "window['gf_submitting_{$form_id}'] = false;" .
                                    '}, 50);' .
                                '}' .
                            'else{' .
                                "jQuery('#gform_{$form_id}').append(contents);" .
                                "if(window['gformRedirect']) {gformRedirect();}" .
                            '}' .
                            "jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [{$form_id}, current_page]);" .
                        '} );' .
                    '} );' . apply_filters( 'gform_cdata_close', '' ) . '</script>';
            }

            $is_first_load = ! $is_postback;

            if ( ( ! $ajax || $is_first_load ) ) {

                self::register_form_init_scripts( $form, $field_values, $ajax );

                if ( apply_filters( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', false ) ) {
                    $callback = array( new GF_Late_Static_Binding( array( 'form_id' => $form['id'] ) ), 'GFFormDisplay_footer_init_scripts' );
                    add_action( 'wp_footer', $callback, 20 );
                    add_action( 'gform_preview_footer', $callback );
                } else {
                    $form_string .= self::get_form_init_scripts( $form );
                    $form_string .= "<script type='text/javascript'>" . apply_filters( 'gform_cdata_open', '' ) . " jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [{$form_id}, {$current_page}]) } ); " . apply_filters( 'gform_cdata_close', '' ) . '</script>';
                }
            }

            return gf_apply_filters( array( 'gform_get_form_filter', $form_id ), $form_string, $form );
        } else {
            $progress_confirmation = '';

            //check admin setting for whether the progress bar should start at zero
            $start_at_zero = rgars( $form, 'pagination/display_progressbar_on_confirmation' );
            $start_at_zero = apply_filters( 'gform_progressbar_start_at_zero', $start_at_zero, $form );

            //show progress bar on confirmation
            if ( $start_at_zero && $has_pages && ! $is_admin && ( $form['confirmation']['type'] == 'message' && $form['pagination']['type'] == 'percentage' ) ) {
                $progress_confirmation = self::get_progress_bar( $form, 0, $confirmation_message );
                if ( $ajax ) {
                    $progress_confirmation = self::get_ajax_postback_html( $progress_confirmation );
                }
            } else {
                //return regular confirmation message
                if ( $ajax ) {
                    $progress_confirmation = self::get_ajax_postback_html( $confirmation_message );
                } else {
                    $progress_confirmation = $confirmation_message;
                }
            }

            return $progress_confirmation;
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо видеть код плагина, тогда можно подумать. А плагин платный, и кода в свободном доступе нет. Другой вариант: можно дать ответ, если форма вставляется шорткодом. В таком случае, покажите, каким.

Comment: @KAGGDesign вставил код и шорткод. Посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде идёт фильтрация через `gf_apply_filters()`. Как там вызываются WordPress-фильтры, непонятно. Поэтому предлагаю решение через перехват вывода шорткода:

```
/**
 * Filters the output created by a shortcode callback.
 *
 * @param string       $output Shortcode output.
 * @param string       $tag    Shortcode name.
 * @param array|string $attr   Shortcode attributes array or empty string.
 * @param array        $m      Regular expression match array.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function my_do_shortcode_tag( $output, $tag, $attr, $m ) {
    if ( 'gravityform' !== $tag ) {
        return $output;
    }

    $search  = [ '<h3 ', '</h3>' ];
    $replace = [ '<div ', '</div>' ];

    return str_replace( $search, $replace, $output );
}

add_filter( 'do_shortcode_tag', 'my_do_shortcode_tag', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: идеально, а правильно ли я понимаю, что 4 аргументом передаём айди формы?

Comment: Нет, все атрибуты (id, title, description, ajax) - в массиве $attr. Сделайте var_dump($attr), увидите.

Comment: спасибо, буду знать :)

Answer (score -1):

смотри, вот эта строка

```
      form_string =.                  <h3 class='gform_title'>" . esc_html( $form['title'] ) . '</h3>';
```

жёстко хардкодит h3?
получи форму как строку и ф-ей str_replace замени фрагмент

Comment: С какой части кода вы это вырезали?